# How to make multi-keystroke function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using Python 3.5. I want to make multi-keystroke function. mean, I want to make a function that notices both `Ctrl + S and Q`. But the program doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
import threading, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1160, 640), 0, 0)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.flip()

def background():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    print('GOOD')

def foreground():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    print('HELLO_WORLD')
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)

b.start()
foreground()
```

The program notices `Q`, but doesn't `Ctrl + S`.

I want to make this program to notice both of them.

How can I make it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should handle all your pygame events from one single thread/place, even if you can use pygame functionlity from other threads... if you still insist on having multiple threads to read keyboard events you share the key state with something like this:

```
import threading
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1160, 640), 0, 0)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.flip()
keys = {
    "mods": 0
}


def background():
    while True:
        mods = keys.get("mods", None)

        if keys["mods"] & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and keys.get(pygame.K_s, False):
            print("GOOD")


def foreground():
    pygame.display.update()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                keys[event.key] = True

                mods = pygame.key.get_mods()
                if mods:
                    keys["mods"] = mods
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                keys[event.key] = False
                keys["mods"] = 0

            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)
b.start()
foreground()
```

But I'd recommend you to avoid this, usually you want to handle all game input in one thread and using other threads to handle different game parts (physics, audio, logic, ...).

That said, my rule of thumb when creating real-time apps is design them as single-thread apps and just using multithreading if it's strictly necessary... but you know what? 90% of cases (real-time apps) you'll see single-threading will be more than good enough, so... [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for late respond.

Answer (score -1):

`pygame.event.get()` consumes events, so you need only one place dealing with events, and check both keys in that single place:

```
   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                print('HELLO_WORLD')
            if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                print('GOOD')
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Don't use two loops in threads, pygame is event-driven anyway so you can just use a single loop.